# Securing database file from being accessed by any other user

Tags: android, database, security, file-permissions

I want to know if we can secure our database file(.db) with password protection. Is there any way to grant access to `.db` file? As I want to apply the mechanism that cannot allow any other user to access my .db file, even if he/she got the `.db` file.

Actually, I am preparing a Backup utility application which can take back up of contacts, sms, gallery files and applications. And backup destination is kept on SDcard. I have successfully completed the first part of contacts. Then I thought of its security that any person could take my SDcard for use and it can take steal my `.db` file to gain my contact details. So is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: How about encrypting the data and then storing it in db ?

Comment: What operating system is this on? Android?

Comment: Yes. I am preparing this application on android 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generall if you store your files in the application directory (on the phone) nobody can access the file except the device is rooted. If you put a file on the sd card every app with the nessesary permission can read all files.

So you need to encrypt the files. I don't know how you write your database, but in general it is it is simple in java to wrap streams. So you can simple add an encryption to your io functions. The classes for this usage are: [CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) for encryption and [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) for decryption.

Comment: This is the only option i see till now. Ciphering the text is enough for securing the data. Thanks for the classes you suggested. I'll definitely go with it.